# Is it possible to integrate game values to a program?

Tags: cheat-engine

This is just an idea and I don't have the slightest clue where to learn this or if this is even possible.
I would assume I should use cheat engine for this.

For example: 
`if(ammo=10) run code`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in numerous different ways. In my opinion though, the easiest way would be to make a program (in C++) that opens a handle to your desired program and reads the memory located at the address of the variable you're trying to check into a buffer located inside your program. You should put this behaviour on a while loop however so that it constantly checks if the 'ammo' value becomes 10. Once it does, you can execute your desired code.